# Reading docs in irb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

One thing I miss about ipython is it has a ? operator which diggs up the docs for a particular function.

I know ruby has a similar command line tool but it is extremely inconvenient to call it while I am in irb.

Does ruby/irb have anything similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Pry](http://pry.github.com) is a Ruby version of IPython, it supports the `?` command to look up documentation on methods, but uses a slightly different syntax:

```
pry(main)> ? File.dirname

From: file.c in Ruby Core (C Method):
Number of lines: 6

visibility:  public
signature:  dirname()

Returns all components of the filename given in file_name
except the last one. The filename must be formed using forward
slashes (/'') regardless of the separator used on the
local file system.

   File.dirname("/home/gumby/work/ruby.rb")   #=> "/home/gumby/work"
```

You can also look up sourcecode with the `$` command:

```
pry(main)> $ File.link

From: file.c in Ruby Core (C Method):
Number of lines: 14

static VALUE
rb_file_s_link(VALUE klass, VALUE from, VALUE to)
{
    rb_secure(2);
    FilePathValue(from);
    FilePathValue(to);
    from = rb_str_encode_ospath(from);
    to = rb_str_encode_ospath(to);

    if (link(StringValueCStr(from), StringValueCStr(to)) < 0) {
    sys_fail2(from, to);
    }
    return INT2FIX(0);
}
```

See http://pry.github.com for more information :)

Comment: Thanks! That's what I really needed!

Comment: Is it possible to include some minimal instruction on how to get to the pry prompt (for noobies)? E.g. install pry and pry-doc `gem install pry && gem install pry-doc`, `require` them both, then inside IRB run the command: `pry`, and *only then* try the code in the answer. I feel like your assumption that people will know this is pretty sound, but it might help for noobies like me to have those first few pointers there too

Answer (score 6):

You can start with

```
irb(main):001:0> `ri Object`
```

Although the output of this is less than readable. You'd need to filter out some metacharacters.

In fact, someone already made [a gem for it](https://github.com/dadooda/ori)

```
gem install ori
```

Then in irb

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'ori'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Object.ri
Looking up topics [Object] o
= Object < BasicObject

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
= Includes:
Java (from gem activesupport-3.0.9)

(from gem activesupport-3.0.9) [...]
```

Comment: +1 for including a simple, practical solution in your answer!

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't. Python has docstrings:

```
def my_method(arg1,arg2):
  """ What's inside this string will be made available as the __doc__ attribute """
  # some code
```

So, when the `?` is called from ipython, it probably calls the `__doc__` attribute on the object. Ruby doesn't have this.